# How to setup libsoup for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install libsoup for my ubuntu environment:

```
checking for LIBSOUP... configure: error: Package requirements (libsoup-2.4 >= 2.28.2) were not met:

No package 'libsoup-2.4' found
```

I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsoup2.4-dev
```

and now it said:

```
checking for LIBSOUP... configure: error: Package requirements (libsoup-2.4 >= 2.28.2) were not met:

Requested 'libsoup-2.4 >= 2.28.2' but version of libsoup is 2.4.1
```

Thanks for any suggestion in how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but for anyone stumbling across this post I fixed this common issue after the following debugging:

---

**IMPORTANT:** The required webkit version may have changed since the OP asked this question, so check the file ~/src/Webkit/configure.ac and search for `LIBSOUP_REQUIRED_VERSION`. If a version other than 2.28.2 is listed, remember to use the correct version in all the commands.

Also at the time of writing, libsoup-2.4 was the latest stable libsoup release. if this is not still the case you will need to replace all mentions of libsoup-2.4 with the correct package name.

Finally, these steps only enabled me to get past the libsoup not found issue. I'm still unable to build webkit during the make phase.

---

The trick is this command: `pkg-config --exists --print-errors 'libsoup-2.4  >= 2.28.2'`.
Basically you need this command to execute without errors (if successful the output will be blank).

1. run `pkg-config --modversion libsoup-2.4` to check the branch of libsoup you are running (mine was 2.38.1)
2. if the result was not as you expected - run `sudo ldconfig` and `sudo updatedb` to ensure your libraries are reporting the latest versions and repeat step 1
3. if your reported version is lower than webkit requires (check ~/src/Webkit/configure.ac and search for `LIBSOUP_REQUIRED_VERSION` ), then you may need to download libsoup source, manually compile & add the new path to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` using `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:absolute_path_to_libsoup_directory`). Your libsoup directory is the one that contains libsoup-2.4.pc.
4. open up ~/src/Webkit/configure.ac again and search for `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBSOUP]`. On the line below this it make sure that the first argument for the comparison exactly matches the package name passed in to pkg-config in step 1 (I had to change `libsoup` to `libsoup-2.4`)
5. run the command `pkg-config --exists --print-errors 'libsoup-2.4  >= 2.28.2'`.
6. run `sudo ./src/Webkit/autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` again and hopefully it'll pass

Answer (score 1):

You can install a more recent version of `libsoup` by downloading it and following the steps in http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/libsoup.html

To make the long story short:

Make sure you have all dependencies, in my Ubuntu 14.04 I needed to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev valac
```

Then compile `libsoup`:

```
sed -i "/seems to be moved/s/^/#/" build-aux/ltmain.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static && make
```

Install `libsoup`:

```
sudo make install
```

Update the database for mlocate:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Make sure the metadata file for `pkg-config` is the correct one:

```
locate libsoup-2.4.pc
```

The output should be in:

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libsoup-2.4.pc
```

Final test:

```
pkg-config --modversion libsoup-2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to fix the configure script of the package you are trying to build as it seems to get the test wrong.

Comment: It is s configure script from the Webkit project.